# Hide link text from statusbar in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a text widget in my wordpress blog. Inside the text widget, i have a link. When mouse is hovered over the link, the link text shows up in the status bar.
To prevent the link text from showing in the status bar i tried using:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="window.status=''" onclick="fun();return false;" >  </a>
```

But, still the link text shows up in the status bar, when mouse is hovered over the link . i guess thats because the link is inside a text widget, so the status bar is inaccessible.

Still, is there any way to hide the link from showing up in the status bar when mouse is hovered over a link inside a text widget in wordpress ?

Thank You.

Comment: `window.status` is sooo late 90s.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone without malicious intent would want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Since hackers abused this for malicious reasons, most browsers don't allow to modify the status line this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want status text in your status bar - don't use link, use button or span, styled as link.